# Django - What happens when a csrf_token is NOT re-submitted to the server?

Tags: django, http, security, django-templates, csrf

**Hello, Everybody.**

I was wondering about... **What happens when a csrf_token is submitted by the server-side application to the browser in an HTML form, and that form was not submitted with the post by the browser?**

Because I was thinking... **Django makes the csrf_token and relates it to the user or to the session, I am not sure, to check it when it comes back. And then I think it deletes it, right? So what if it wasn't back?
Will it stay there waiting until the session ends** or **It is a mistake that causes vulnerability or what?**

For **Example**, I want to make a form for **Comments** under the details of the object. But it is not a must to comment. You **can** comment if you need, and you **can do not** so. So I put a form like this under those details :

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Here is the object data -->
</div>

<div class="container comments">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <form action="{% url 'ads:newcomment' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <input id="comment_txt" name="comment" type="text" value="Type a comment..." class="comment_txt"/>        
            </form>
        </li>
        {% for comment in comments %}
        <li class="comment">{{comment}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSRF token data lives in the request session or in the cookies depending on your settings.

When you do `{% csrf_token %}` the same token is put into a hidden field on your form so that it get's POSTed back to the server.
The server will just compare that it matches what it in the sesssion/cookie.

A similar thing is done for AJAX requests, but rather than including it in the body, it is part of the headers.

If you use `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True` or `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True` the token cannot be accessed via JavaScript so it's pretty safe.

The token itself is randomly generated and used throughout a user's session (i.e if they logout and login again a different token will be generated).

So to answer your question, **if the form is not submitted nothing happens**. The CSRF token will continue to exist in the session/cookies as long as the user is logged in.

Refer to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/) for more details